# RVO при выводе типа decltype(auto)

Tags: c++, rvo

Формулировка RVO, по книге Скотта Мейерса "Эффективный и современный C++", гласит, что такое разрешение даётся, если 1) тип локального объекта совпадает с возвращаемым функцией и 2) локальный объект представляет собой возвращаемое значение.

Также приводятся примеры, вроде:

```
Widget foo() {
    Widget w;
    return w;
}
```

Вопрос заключеется в следующем - верно ли я понимаю, что при использовании вывода типа возвращаемого аргумента с использованием decltype(auto) (или более старой версии, для C++11):

```
decltype(auto) foo() {
    Widget w;
    return w;
}
```

, выводимый тип будет совпадать с типом возвращаемого локального объекта, удовлетворяя условию (1), соответственно RVO, в данном случае, имеет место быть? Или же сам факт того, что тип выводится, является противоречием для условия (1)?

Comment: Вы понимаете верно.

Comment: Только это NRVO, а не RVO.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat согласен, ошибся, однако сути вопроса не меняет